# Uploading PDF file on the server

Tags: php, pdf

```
<form name="frmlist" id="frmlist" action="check.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="400" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20">1</td>
                        <td width="220"><span class="form_title">User Name:<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="username" value="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20">2</td>
                        <td width="120"><span class="form_title">Password<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="password" value="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20">3</td>
                        <td width="120"><span class="form_title">File<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="filepdf" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="new_user" value="SUBMIT" class="sub">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my simple form to upload a PDF file with username and password but jus concentrate on PDF only. So when I upload PDF file and `print_r` on the other page ie `check.php` it gives me a result like this :

> Array ( [name] => Catalogue.pdf [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your code seems to run fine for me. Try uploading other file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not mistaken error 1 is for exceeded the max upload size (explanation here http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

To increase go to your php.ini file and change it to something bigger and then restart/reload webserver.

> ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
>   ; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
>   upload_max_filesize = 10M